# Read the values from properties file in pester

Tags: powershell, properties-file, pester

I want to read the data from properties file in powershell using pester framework, but facing an error.

Properties file:

```
vmsize1='Standard_D3_V2'
vmsize2='Standard_DS1_V2'
```

Code:

```
 Context "VIRTUAL MACHINE" {

        $file_content = get-content "$here/properties.txt" -raw     
        $configuration = ConvertFrom-String($file_content)
        $environment = $configuration.'vmsize1' 

        It "CHECKING THE SIZE OF VM" {
            $environment | Should -Be "Standard_D3_V2"
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Context VIRTUAL MACHINE
      [-] CHECKING THE SIZE OF VM 78ms
        Expected 'Standard_D3_V2', but got $null.
        694:             $environment | Should -Be "Standard_D3_V2"
```

Please help me to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable by changing your code slightly.

```
$configuration = ConvertFrom-StringData(get-content "$here/properties.txt" -raw)
$configuration.vmsize1
```

However this is not the nicest way and I would suggest using JSON as I have found this much easier to serialize in PowerShell. Save this as your `properties.json` file

```
{
    "vm1": {
        "size": "Standard_D3_V2"
    },
    "vm2": {
        "size": "Standard_D3_V2"
    }
}
```

your code would look like

```
$fileContent = Get-Content "$here/properties.json" -raw
$configuration = ConvertFrom-Json $fileContent
$configuration.vm1.size
```

This way would make it easier to update due to the rigidness of JSON and would also allow you to add extra properties in the future as your code expands.

Comment: Its working as expected! Thank you for your help. Yeah sure i will look into suggestion and i think it will be helpful to us

Comment: If this is working for you please can you accept it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: can u help me to find out the solution of below question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51723037/not-able-to-fetch-the-individual-details-from-json-data

Comment: @ParthMakwana if this has worked for you please can you mark it as the correct answer to help users in the future