# Not able to fetch the individual details from JSON data

Tags: powershell, pester

```json
"Ns": {
    "value": [
        {
            "Nname": "exa",
            "SR": [
                {
                    "name": "port1",
                    "properties": {
                        "description": "Allow port1",
                        "destinationPortRange": "1111",
                        "priority": 100
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "port1_0",
                    "properties": {
                        "description": "Allow port1",
                        "destinationPortRange": "1111",
                        "priority": 150
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "port2",
                    "properties": {
                        "description": "Allow  1115",
                        "destinationPortRange": "1115",
                        "priority": 100,
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Want to assert the details of priority and name  but was not able to do it.

Here is what I have implemented:

```bsh
$Ndetails = templateProperties.parameters.Ns.value.SR
foreach ($Ndata in $Ndetails) {
    $Ndata .properties.destinationPortRange |
        Should -BeExactly @('1111','1111','1115')
}
```

How to resolve the same using Pester in PowerShell?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, can you check it and correct?

Comment: It's Correct ! Help me to identify the unique values and how to point that parameter

Comment: Here's a valid version of the JSON: https://pastebin.com/qjKG5mrC

Comment: yes , it is! now to how to call that priority and destination port address values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `foreach` for this. You can just use `Select-Object` for this. Assuming your JSON is as [@Mark Wragg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2796058/mark-wragg) linked in the comments:

```
$Json = @'
[{
    "Ns": {
        "value": [{
            "Nname": "exa",
            "SR": [{
                    "name": "port1",
                    "properties": {
                        "description": "Allow port1",
                        "destinationPortRange": "1111",
                        "priority": 100
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "port1_0",
                    "properties": {
                        "description": "Allow port1",
                        "destinationPortRange": "1111",
                        "priority": 150
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "port2",
                    "properties": {
                        "description": "Allow  1115",
                        "destinationPortRange": "1115",
                        "priority": 100
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
}]
'@
 
$t = $Json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Your test file should look like this:

```
$result = $t.Ns.value.SR.properties.destinationPortRange
it 'destinationPortRange matches' {
  $result | Should -BeExactly @('1111','1111','1115')
}
```

---

#### Explanation

Your use of `foreach` was incorrect as you compared single element (also notice that I deleted unnecessary space)

```
$Ndata.properties.destinationPortRange
```

to the array

```
| Should -BeExactly @('1111','1111','1115')
```

What you have to do is to compare array to array as in my example.

Comment: working as expected! Thank you so much for your help.